# making list<struct> out of memory c#

Tags: c#

I have the below code To save data table data in to list I have 1 million records in datatable but after 524288 row I get this error 
An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
how can I resolve it?

thanks

```
public struct Dg {
    public int Id;
    public int b;
}

public List<Dg> DgShow() { 
    List<Dg> list_m = new List<Dg>(); 
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) { 
        for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++) { 
            Dg a = new Dg(); 
            a.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString()); 
            a.b = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Idb"].ToString()); 
            list_m.Add(a); 
        } 
    } 
    return list_m;
}
```

Comment: Please add you code to your question next time. Unformatted code as a comment is pretty unreadable.

Comment: Easiest troll-answer possible: add more memory. But jokes aside:
Why would you want to keep a list of all those id's in memory? You have a datatable to read from, so I assume you have a database to read from too.
Besides that, two minor points; the "if > 0" is not needed, the for loop handles that already : it can not loop if the i < rowsCount so it won't. 
And you don't need to cast to string before casting to int. But those are minor.

Comment: is the code even compiled? noted the data type of a should be `Dg`;

Comment: Clearly enough - you haven't show actual code. For example, your `list_m` of type `List<Dg>`, but you're adding to it object of type `DgShowTA_Manage_Darkhast_column`. So maybe problem is in your `Dg` structure size. If it is too big (not only two ints you've showed) - you may hit 2Gb limit per object with your `List<Dg>`.

Comment: I found it is related to int i,so I changedt it to int 64

Answer (score 3):

If you were actually adding instances of `Dg` to the list, you would be able to add nearly 70 million. The type being added, `DgShowTA_Manage_Darkhast_column`, must be much larger for you to fail at just half a million.

In this scenario, I think the easiest thing for you to do is change the type `DgShowTA_Manage_Darkhast_column` from `struct` to `class`, if possible. It's obviously a large type, so you're not really gaining much making it a value type, and it's just as obviously impeding your ability to maintain as large a collection as you want.

There are other approaches you can take:

- store the data in some hierarchical data structure (e.g. list of lists)
- don't store that much data in memory at all (e.g. write queries that do preliminary processing on the database side so that the in-memory data structures don't have to be so big)

If you could provide a better code example and more context, perhaps a better answer could be provided.

Comment: I have a silverlight application I select my data in server side and put them in a list<struc> and send this list to client side to show it in a gridview,it works until records number in less but after 524288 I get out of memory error

Comment: Where are you running this Silverlight app? On a phone? In any case, Silverlight is significantly constrained as compared to a normal desktop app; you should have mentioned that in your question (and should update the tags to reflect that). I think it's entirely possible in Silverlight that you are genuinely out of memory, not just hitting the 2GB/object limit in .NET. In that case, you need to pursue a solution that involves not keeping all of the data in memory all at once (i.e. my last suggestion).